# Sort by substring in views?

Tags: views

I have a content type with a full person's name in the title, in the format "John Smith". I want to have a view that sorts this content by last name. I've looked at the views interface but I don't see a way to get a substring. (I understand that this won't work perfectly but for our data set, it will work well enough.)

Will I have to add a field of the last name to the content type? Or is there a way I can get views to sort by a substring?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new field for the last name will be the easiest way. Sorting by a substring would mean that you also have to cover the possibility of spaces in first names and/or last names.